# Dominant map from projective space of a correct dimension

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a $d$-dimensional integral variety over an algebraically closed field $k$ and let $f\colon \mathbb{P}^n_k --> X$ be a dominant rational map. Why does this imply that there is a dominant rational map $g\colon \mathbb{P}^d_k --> X$?

Supposedly, the restriction of $f$ to a sufficiently "general" subspace $\mathbb{P}^d_k \subset \mathbb{P}^n_k$ should give a desired $g$, but I can't see how to prove that a single such subspace exists.

Comment: The general fiber $Z$ of $f$ is a $(n-d)$-dimensional subvariety of $\mathbb{P}^n$. A general $\mathbb{P}^d\subset \mathbb{P}^n$ will meet $Z$ along a finite subset (if you don't see this, start with $d=n-1$ and proceed by induction). Thus the fiber of $f_{|\mathbb{P}^d}$ at a general point of $X$ is finite. This implies that  $f_{|\mathbb{P}^d}$ is dominant.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://mathoverflow.net/questions/95306/discussion-of-luroths-problem-in-an-article-of-beauville/95367#95367

Comment: @ArtiePrendergast-Smith — I think the question is not exactly a duplicate, but your answer does answer this question. On the other hand, OP indicate that they knows the rough sketch of your answer, but don't know why the *sufficiently "general" subspace* exists. I think this justifies this question.

Comment: @abx: Thanks, but could you explain in a bit more detail (that would be very helpful)? Is $Z$ *the* generic fiber or *a* general fiber. My stumbling point is that "a general fiber" $Z$ is really infinitely many fibers parametrized by an open of $X$, so even though I could convince myself that each one of them has a finite intersection with most $\mathbb{P}^d$'s, I don't see how to guarantee finite intersection with every one $Z$ over that open. On the other hand, if $Z$ is *the* generic fiber, then I don't know how to argue finite intersection, because $Z$ then consists of non-closed points.

Comment: @Lisa S. : Just take *one* fiber (above a closed point $x\in X$) of dimension $n-d$. Then $f_{|\mathbb{P}^d}$ has finite fibers above $x$, hence above a Zariski open subset of $X$.